# What happens to installable time-driver triggers when a Google Sheets document closes?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Seeing as a simple time-driven script runs whether the Sheet is open or not, I now have installable time-driven functions instantiated when the onOpen function is evaluated. My question is: what happens when the document is closed? Do the time-driven functions continue to execute? If so, is there a way to tell them not to do unless the document is open?

Comment: A1: The time-driven trigger is run independently whether the Google Docs is opened or closed. A2: I think that unfortunately, it is difficult to know whether the Google Docs is closed on the browser. So the time-driven trigger can be run when the Google Docs is opened. But it is required to think of the method for stopping the the trigger. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, the problem is regarding stopping the timer when it is so easy to stop the instance of Google Sheets in an unmanaged/uncontrolled manner, viz, closing the browser tab it's in.

Comment: To expand on @Tanaike 's answer, when a time-driven trigger is run, it opens its own instance of the file, so it runs independently from anything else you're doing. In a sense, you already pressed the run button. What you can do is having checks in your code to manage when the trigger is run. For example, if you have a daily trigger but you don't want it to run on weekends, you can have a function `a` that checks the day of the week, and if it's on a week day, run your intended function `b`, then you would just set the trigger with `a` and `b` would only run on weekdays.

Comment: However, I have it running every 15 seconds. I will tie its run more closely to the script properties array that contains tasks.